# Django - Render view based on search query from search view

Tags: python, django

I have what is probably a very basic question. I have read through [Django forms docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/) but am still missing something here. I want to have a search bar in one template (`search.html`) and return the search query in another template (`results.html`). I have the following so far, using [this SO answer as a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27300680/django-passing-a-variable-from-a-view-into-a-url-tag-in-template), which returns the following error. Thanks for any help.

```
Exception Value:    
results() missing 1 required positional argument: 'search_id'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^landing/', views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^results/', views.results, name='results'),
]
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import Apartment
class Apt(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = Apartment
      fields = ('name')
```

**views.py**

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': #the form has been submitted
        form = Apt(request.POST) #bound form
        if form.is_valid(): #validations have passed
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            u = Apt.objects.create(name=name)
            #REST query will go here.

            #commit to database
            u.save()

            return redirect('results', search_id=u.name)

    else: #create an unbound instance of the form
        form = Apt(initial={'name':'name'})
    #render the form according to the template, context = form
    return render(request, 'search/landing.html', {'form':form})

def results(request, search_id):
    search_id = request.POST.get('name')
    query = get_object_or_404(Apt, pk=search_id)
    return render(request, 'search/results.html', {'query':query} )
```

**landing.html**

```
{% extends "base_simple.html" %}

{% block title %}Look up your name{% endblock %}

{% block main_content %}

<!-- Intro Header -->
<header class="intro">
    <div class="intro-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="inner cover">
            <h1 class="cover-heading">find your name</h1>
            <form id="searchform" method="POST" action="" accept-charset="utf-8">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <input id="apt" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apartment Name" value="{{ Apt.name }}">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
            </form>
          </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

{% endblock %}
```

**results.html**

```
{% extends "base_simple.html" %}

{% block title %}search results{% endblock %}

{% block main_content %}

<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        {% for q in query %}
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h3>{{ q.name }}</h3>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}    
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

in urls you need to change result to

```
url(r'^results/(?P<search_id>.+)/', views.results, name='results'),
```

Named groups in the regex are passed as arguments to the view

You should also remove the line `search_id = request.POST.get('name')` from your results view as the redirect will not contain any POST data

Comment: thanks. I changed the url and removed the `search_id` but now am getting the error: `Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'results' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['results/(?P<search_id>.+)/']` when I go to the landing url

Comment: Are you using the "results" view in a url tag? or in another reverse?

Comment: You should remove `action="{% url 'results' %}"` from your landing template. You are handling form validation in your search view

Comment: Removed the url tag. Now, the `landing.html` simply refreshes when hitting submit

Comment: Your `form` is not valid

Comment: I don't understand what that means

Comment: Place the tag `{{form.errors}}` somewhere in the form in your landing template and the error message will tell you more

Comment: `{{form.errors}}` says `name This field is required`. But I am including the name here